# Explain this dynamic ng-model different behaviors?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**1 :**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newObject[$index]"> // this works fine
   </li>
</ul>
```

**2 :**

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newObject.something[$index]"> // this is not working
   </li>
</ul>
```

In angular controller,

```
$scope.newObject = {};
$scope.items = [{name:'foo'}, {name:'bar'}, {name:'baz'}];
```

**1** is working as expected. but **2** is not working as previous one, Cant type inside the textbox. what is going in here, and how should I solve this. thanks :)

**update**

solve this issue by adding this line inside the controller

```
$scope.newObject.something = {};
```

but i dont know why its working, can someone please explain this ?

Comment: Is newObject.something and object or array?

Comment: In javascrit a dot follow open bracket is a ilegal expression try this: newObject.something[$index]

Comment: @cbass its an Object

Comment: You needed to create the object

Comment: I don't see the error works perfectly here http://plnkr.co/edit/oCRrKjsN2HxZKOq9JKyn?p=preview

Comment: OMG yeah, seems like nagular version matters, im using `1.2.15` thats why I think :), thanks for the concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the property `something` doesn't exist on `newObject` until you define it - so there's an error being thrown when trying to bind back to the model.

Declare your model first:

```
$scope.newObject = {
    something: {}
}
```

`$scope.newObject[$index]` looks for the `$index` property on `newObject` - if not found it'll create it. When you have `$scope.newObject.something[$index]` it looks for the `something` property - doesn't find it, therefore can't bind to the additional `$index` property 1 layer deeper.

Simple JavaScript really:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.something = "k"; //works fine
myObj.something.somemore = "x"; //works fine
myobj.somethingnew.somemorenew = "j"; //throws error because the property "somethingnew" doesn't exist, therefore "somemorenew" cannot be created as a child property
```